# Can't access episode 2 in "Lego Star Wars the Complete Saga"

Tags: lego-star-wars

How do I get to episode 2 in LSW TCS. I completed episode one and tried to go to episode two but it didn’t let me go to episode two in LSW even though it’s supposed to be “the complete saga”

Comment: There's no message indicating why? Older LSW games required getting enough of the hidden "minifig" collectibles to unlock a given level. Requires Free Play so keeps people playing longer and exploring more, which helps make it feel like the game is worth the price to many people.

Comment: Can you tell us what error message you're getting?  Can you include a screen shot?

Comment: Is this what you get to? https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaXbv.jpg